# connection string to db access

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection-string

I have a finished project in aspx.cs everything it's working. It's time to see the light, time to publish.

I also have a folder with the database "db/database.accdb"

however before publish I need put in web.config a "connection string" to BD Access, for been able modify (if necessary) without recompile the app.

This is what I have in my web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
    <!-- falso para ISS-->
    </system.web>

  <system.web>
  <authorization> <!-- windows authorization IIS EXPRESS (F4) ENABLE senão dá erro -->
    <deny users = "?" /> <!-- nega acesso utilizadores anónimos -->
    <allow users ="*" /> <!-- dá acesso a todos os utilizadores -->
  </authorization>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't think you need to rebuild app again for config change. Recycle app pool should be good enough if you host in IIS.

Comment: @MattRowland sry my question is what changes i need to do in my web.config to connection string db access

Comment: @rajasekharareddy "Recycle app pool" hmmm sry don't follow... what you mean?

Comment: Just like @rajasekharareddy said. You have to rebuild the app for a config change. Just setup the connection string before you build it. If the app/file system is going to change for deployment then you need to anticipate that and code in the correct connection string for the new location.